# Is there an equivalent to xmlDoc.LoadXml(myStr) from C# in Python3?

Tags: c#, python, python-3.6

Well, recently I started learning python, I try to use/discover more from the language. I have a project. I need to handle xml files. I know from `.NET C#` I can load a `xmlObject` from a `String` using:

```
xmlDoc.LoadXml(myStr)
```

I wonder (also I have try to use and understand `lxml` and `xml`) how to get this done, but I could not.

Thank you in advanced

C# Code

```
Dim xmlDoc As New Xml.XmlDocument()
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(myStr)
```

---

Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

To parse from string use [`xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(text, parser=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring).

You can use it like this, as recommended in docs:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(yourxmlstring)
```

Comment: Hi, But Exception has occurred: AttributeError
module 'xml' has no attribute 'etree'

Comment: You need to `import xml.etree.ElementTree`.

Comment: I did  the import statement.

Comment: Check my edit on the answer and see if the problem continues.